# In kubernetes, How to access the environment variable inside the configmap?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have use-case to append pod name into "**jdbc_db_url**" property. which locate in "**common-configmap.config**" file.  In order to achieve I have followed the below steps, but unfortunately unable to make it.

**Step 1:**
**common-configmap.config**

```
# Database Properties
jdbc_auto_commit=false

jdbc_postgresql_driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc_db_url=jdbc:postgresql://dev.postgres.database.azure.com/dbname?ApplicationName=${POD_NAME}
```

**Step 2:**
Using below command deploying configmap into cluster

```
kubectl create configmap common-configmap --from-env-file /app/conf/common-configmap.config -n default
```

**Step 3:**
Using below manifest files created the "myapp" container and service

Deployment Manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: master
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 4.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: myapp-4.0.0
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 5
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: myapp-configmap
        - configMapRef:
            name: common-configmap
        image: docker.com/myapp:4.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: myapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Service Manifest file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: master
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 4.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: myapp-4.0.0
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
 - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

verifying the result I have getting into a shell running container and print the environment variables:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty myapp-d5db776b9-h25q5 -c myapp -- /bin/sh
```

**Actual Result:**

```
# printenv

jdbc_auto_commit=false
jdbc_postgresql_driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc_db_url=jdbc:postgresql://dev.postgres.database.azure.com/dbname?ApplicationName=${POD_NAME}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
jdbc_auto_commit=false
jdbc_postgresql_driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc_db_url=jdbc:postgresql://dev.postgres.database.azure.com/dbname?ApplicationName=myapp-d5db776b9-h25q5
```

- How do I substitute the environment variable in config-map while
  deploying/container runtime?  or Is there any other way how to
  pass/substitute the **pod_name** in the **JDBC_URL**
- May i know, What did I do wrong in this case?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Will you use `deployment` in your use case or a static pod? If static pod then the name will not change and it can be used in configmap

Comment: Not a static pod name.. Will use deployment

Comment: A better way to deal with this would be to create a service (with type ClusterIP) for your deployment and then add the service name inside the configmap instead the pod name. Service name is not changing unlike the pod name, also by doing this you may add more replicas in your deployment later.

Comment: Thanks. Now i have created container with the deployment and service (with type ClusterIP) manifest. please let know how i need to  refer the service name and i have attached the deployment and service manifest also

Comment: you can refer to the service by _myapp.default_ (<service-name>.<namespace>)

Comment: sorry i'm unable to follow your suggestion. could you please help me with some example's.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with an init-container which has a shared volume of type `emptyDir` between it and your main container.

First, edit your deployment to add an `emptyDir` volume and an init container, and mount the volume to both containers:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: master
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 4.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: myapp-4.0.0
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 5
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    spec:
      volumes: # emptyDir volume for the entire pod
        - name: config-volume
          emptyDir: {}
      initContainers: # an init container that will compile the env var with the pod name
      - name: config-compiler
        image: bash
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-compiler
          mountPath: /configs
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: common-configmap
        command: 
        - bash
        - -c
        - 'echo $jdbc_db_url | sed "s/POD_NAME/${POD_NAME}/" > /configs/compiled.env'
      containers:
      - volumeMounts:
        - name: config-compiler
          mountPath: /configs
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: myapp-configmap
        - configMapRef:
            name: common-configmap
        image: docker.com/myapp:4.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: myapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Then, you'll need to make sure that your actual pod is reading the env vars file - you can either do that by editing your entrypoint script to add a line like so:

```
source /configs/compiled.env
```

or edit the the command of your pod to something like so:

```yaml
command: [ 'source', '/configs/compiled.env;', 'previous-command' ]
```

Both of the above are a bit hack-ish - so what I recommend doing, is to see what config files your app reads by default, and to match your compiling script to those.

For example, if your app reads from `/etc/myapp/confs.d/files.env` - mount your empty dir to `/etc/myapp/confs.d` and have the init container write to `files.env`, and do so in the format your app expects (e.g. if it's an ini file instead of an env file, compile it so it will match that format)

And obviously there are better ways to compile a config file then with `sed` - but it's an option if you want (and can afford) to keep things short

Comment: Thanks for your input. After implementing following, Error occurs while deploying: failed to start container "myapp": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: From that - I imagine that you chose to change the command of your container, to something that tries to use bash. If that's true, try to change `bash` to `sh` as most containers don't have bash installed. Also, what image are you using for the init container? I chose bash because it should contain `sed` which fits my example - but you might have chosen something different

Comment: Thanks for your input. now I able to replace the value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward way you can do that is to use a simple command in your deployment, assume the JDBC_URL value will be used only in the sample pod. Otherwise, you can have similar logic in your custom base image if you have any, or in an init container.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: master
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 4.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: myapp-4.0.0
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 5
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: master
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: myapp-configmap
        - configMapRef:
            name: common-configmap
        image: docker.com/myapp:4.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: myapp
        command: 
        - bash
        - -c
        - export JDBC_URL=$(echo $JDBC_URL | sed "s/POD_NAME/${POD_NAME}/1")
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Please note the code snippet I inserted:

```
    command: 
    - bash
    - -c
    - export JDBC_URL=$(echo $JDBC_URL | sed "s/POD_NAME/${POD_NAME}/1")
```